# How to force an Update to android TextClock while App is running

Tags: android, widget

I have a unique situation. My Application periodically needs to synchronize the Android clock, date and time with our host PC. We do this via a docking cradle and a command sent to Android via ADB.

I have confirmed that the Date and Time actually do get updated on the Android device - but with my Application running, my displayed TextClock widget does not get updated - it still displays the old time.

For instance - if I go into Android - Settings and set the clock to 11:00 PM, then connect the device via USB to my host PC which is set to 5:00 PM, the clock does get set to 5:00 PM under the hood in Android, but the TextClock still displays 11:00 PM

There really is no code to show for this problem as the Widget is defined in my main view layout.

Does anyone know how I can force the time being displayed in the TextClock Widget to be updated when the Android clock is updated?

Again, I am updating the Android clock using ADB and my App is still running when I do this.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Looking at the implementation of `TextClock` it updates every ~1s, so I don't think the problem is there. It has to be that the method you are using for setting the time isn't triggering System.currentTimeMillis()` to update (which is what `TextClock` reads). Did you try calling `System.setCurrentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: No - didn't try that but I will in the morning and let you know.

Comment: OK, making a call to SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(time); seems to fix my issue. Since that call needs a long to represent the current time I first go get that value using long time = System.currentTimeMillis();.

Since I verified that the Date and Time have actually been reset by my ADB call I simply go get the value, then set the system clock which triggers an update to the TextClock widget.

Comment: long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(time);
                            Utilities.writeToLog("Date Change detected. Resetting GUI.", logFile);
                            TextView txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
                            String ct = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
                            txtDate.setText(ct);